# Right way to wait for a link to click in selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a web page with the following:

```
<a id="show_more" class="friends_more" onclick="Friends.showMore(-1)"
                                                            style="display: block;">
  <span class="_label">Show More Friends</span><span class="friends_more_icon"></span>
</a>
```

I want to click this link in Python 3.5 with Selenium in Chrome browser. If I use `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, id_text)))` and then go ahead and click it, nothing happens.
However, if I wait after `WebDriverWait` returns a clickable element - I'm able to click it.
I have tried 2 ways to click the link:

```
more_friends_link = wait_for_id("show_more", driver)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more_friends_link).click(more_friends_link).perform()
```

And

```
more_friends_link = wait_for_id("show_more", driver)
more_friends_link.click()
```

And both of the ways work fine if wait additionally after `WebDriverWait` returns the element. I don't mind waiting, but I want to figure out why this happens, as none of the click methods throw an exception which makes me think that the element is present, visible and clickable, yet it doesn't respond to a click.

UPD: I forgot to mention that the script worked fine until the site changed its design. Previously the link could be found by link text and click worked just fine.

UPD2: So currently my code looks like this:

```
    more_friends_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "show_more")))
    time.sleep(5)
    more_friends_link.click()
```

an my goal is to replace the `time.sleep(5)` with something more meaningful

Comment: What if you add `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", more_friends_link)` before the click?

Comment: Still no luck either - have just tried that :(  the element is visible within the browser windowб by the way.

Comment: From what I understand (I can only be guessing at this point) is that the "show more" button is getting disabled while the current page/set of friends is being loaded. It is probably disabled in a non-traditional way..in any case, consider adding a link to the target page if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that is currently working? I know you described it but I'm not clear on what you are saying. It sounds like you are stacking waits and that makes it work. It seems like if you removed the first wait and kept the second wait, that should work without two waits... but it's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: You're right, currently I'm doing 2 waits. I edited the question to reflect it. However, the questions are: why the first one stopped working with the design change? and is there a more Pythonic way than just `time.sleep()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, id_text)))
```

with

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id_text)))
```

Comment: Nope, still no luck, unfortunately. By the way, if it wasn't clickable, wouldn't `click()` method throw an exception?

Comment: If element was found, but it's not clickable, there wouldn't be any exception- just no actions

Comment: Well, anyway, changing to `EC.element_to_be_clickable` didn't help so far

Comment: It would actually throw a timeout exception waiting for the element to be clickable and it never became clickable.

Comment: @JeffC Question was about `click()` method, but not `EC.element_to_be_clickable()`

Comment: I read it differently. I read it as a question in response to your proposed code change. If the element wasn't clickable, it would throw an exception waiting to find it before click() could be called. How would you click an element returned by a wait for element to be clickable that wasn't clickable? Maybe I misunderstood the question... it wasn't clear to me what OP was asking, if not what I said.